# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: reactjs, backend, frontend

recien este es mi tercer proyecto. Estoy realizando un ecommerce con back y front.funcionaba perfecto pero de un momento arroja este error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tengo configuradas las cors desde el back mediante
app.use (cors ());